# Django Forms API - Forms Returning Blank

Tags: django, django-forms

I am not getting any data back through the form. I'm obviously missing something but I don't know what.

[I'm following this documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/)

**forms.py**

```
class EventRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    tags = forms.TextInput()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = [
            'name', 'description', 'type', 'map_pin', 'location_id', 'location_name', 'address1',
            'address2', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'country', 'admission_fee', 'free_admission', 'online_ticket_url',
            'available_parking', 'nearby_transit', 'stream', 'kid_friendly', 'no_underage', 'website_url', 'opportunities'
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
def save_event(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":

        main_form_data = json.loads(request.POST.get('mainForm'))
        print(main_form_data)
        main_form = EventRegistrationForm(main_form_data)
        if main_form.is_valid():
            print("Form is incorrectly returning as valid")
            print(main_form.cleaned_data)
```

**output**:

```
{'online_ticket_url': '', 'state': '', 'city': '', 'stream': '', 'name': 'Test Subject', 'description': '', 'type': None, 'no_underage': 'on', 'map_pin': '', 'available_parking': '', 'opportunities': '', 'address': '', 'free_admission': 'on', 'kid_friendly': 'on', 'nearby_transit': '', 'tags': '', 'location_name': '', 'admission_fee': '', 'website_url': '', 'zip': '', 'location_id': '', 'country': ''}
Form is incorrectly returning as valid
{}
```

Would appreciate some help if anyone can tell where I'm getting tripped up.

EDIT: This is what I get in the shell. I think I am misunderstanding how these are supposed to work:

```
>>> a = EventRegistrationForm({"name":"Adam"})
>>> a.is_valid()
True
>>> a.cleaned_data
{}
```

Comment: Could you show us the models?

Comment: I've posted them

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a lot of your fields in your model, `blank=True`, that's why your form is returning valid when no value is provided. If you read the documentation, `blank=True` allows the fields to be blank in ModelForms.

You could override in your `__init__()` method and set `required=True`,

```
class EventRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    tags = forms.TextInput()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = [
            'name', 'description', 'type', 'map_pin', 'location_id', 'location_name', 'address1',
            'address2', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'country', 'admission_fee', 'free_admission', 'online_ticket_url',
            'available_parking', 'nearby_transit', 'stream', 'kid_friendly', 'no_underage', 'website_url', 'opportunities'
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].required = True
```

Comment: But shouldn't it at least fail on a blank `description` and a blank `type`? Also, that doesn't explain why I'm not getting any cleaned data back when I submit a valid `name`. It says the form is valid, but there is nothing in my `cleaned_data`.

Comment: I tried setting required to true by using the code you shared, but the issue is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. For some reason, this form was set up using a standard form (`forms.Form`) instead of a model form (`forms.ModelForm`). Therefore, none of my fields were being registered...

```
class EventRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ....
```